# How to get text from a read only element using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to get the text from the Read-Only text box.
This textbox contains a text that is system generated and hence its a non-editable field.
I tried the below code but not able to capture the text.

```
var expectedText = element(by.id('txt_ANNOUNCEMENTID')).getText();
```

Below is the HTML for the element:

```
<input name="ANNOUNCEMENTID" id="txt_ANNOUNCEMENTID" ng-focus="formName[name].hasFocus=true" ng-blur="formName[name].hasFocus=false; blur()" type="text" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="" my-maxlength="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-readonly="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="1" ng-trim="false" readonly="readonly">
```

Any help on the above issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getAttribute(value)` instead of `getText()` when trying get the value from  textbox.

In your case, it should be like                `element(by.id('txt_ANNOUNCEMENTID')).getAttribute("value");`